# Windows SDK UWP App Error - DEP3321

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I have been battling **DEP3321: To deploy this application, your deployment target should be running Windows Universal Runtime version 10.0.14393.0 or higher. You currently are running version 10.0.10586.839. Please update your OS, or change your deployment target to a device with the appropriate version.** for the past few days.

I have a UWP app which I cannot run on my machine. However, if I select one of the emulators, it runs fine. I have also set the minimum target value which ensures that the app runs, however, the app throws an error as it cannot find some methods in the lower version on the SDK.

I have tried repairing and uninstalling/re-installing both visual studio 2015 and 2017. I have tried the same with the various windows SDK as well. At one point i had three different versions of the SDK installed and visual studio was still complaining even though i had the updated version installed. Currently, I have installed win sdk 10.0.15063.17.

Any ideas what I can do next to resolve this issue. I have trawled various SO pages as well social.msdn pages with no luck.

Many thanks

Answer (score 9):

I also encountered the same problem

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       DEP3321: To deploy this application, your deployment target should be running Windows Universal Runtime version 10.0.17763.0 or higher. You currently are running version 10.0.17134.648. Please update your OS, or change your deployment target to a device with the appropriate version.

Solution:
Right click on the project property and got to the General-> Target Platform Minimum version.
In my case, I changed it to "10.0.17134.0" by selecting from the drop-down and then rebuilt it.
I worked well. Attached snapshot for reference.[image]

Answer (score 8):

I just started a new app and selected the highest Target levels and got this error. I was able to get rid of this error by selecting the default minimum Min Target Version as shown below.
[image: Change UWP Properties]

Comment: Here's another attempt to get it to work with one of the demos I just downloaded from MS... I'm getting the same error even after downgrading the Min version... https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028685/windows-10-get-the-fall-creators-update

Answer (score 3):

If your app is using APIs that only exist in newer versions of the OS (like 14393 or 15063), then you won't be able to call those on 10586. You will get an exception because the method simply doesn't exist on that machine.

In order to support the app on lower versions of the operating system you will need to wrap the calls to those APIs with an appropriate "IsAPIPresent" check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stefan. The issue here is not that I need to get the app to work on the lower version. The issue is that even when i install 14393 or higher versions, visual studio still complains about the dependency issue. From what I understand is that VS is not picking up the correct version of the SDK. I checked all over the place including registry entries to no awail.

Comment: By "when I install 14393" do you mean the 14393 SDK? If so then what you see is the expected behavior. The SDK only enables you to build the app for a certain version of the SDK. In order to deploy and run your OS needs to have the required minversion. So if your app declares minversion=14393 then it won't deploy or run on 10586. Keep in mind that the Windows APIs are interfaces for native OS features. If they are not present in your version of the OS the API will not work. Installing the SDK does not add those OS features, it just enables access to the API for the build process.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info Stefan, really appreciate your input. What you stated makes sense. So I am running windows 10 on my machine and so is my colleague. Both of us have the same hardware specs and he can run the app with no issues at all. The issue I faced is when I installed the 14393 or 15063, it seemed to me that visual studio was not recognizing the update. Maybe it was, if the app compiled. I only got the error when i tried to run the app.

Comment: Am i correct in understanding that Universal Runtime version  = SDK version? If not, how do I determine the Universal Runtime version on my machine? And the only way to update Universal Runtime version is to update my OS?

Answer (score 2):

Possible Solution:
I was facing with the EXACT same issue. I have my SDK 15063, and I have installed Visual Studio 2017 afresh, which also installed SDK 15063 implicitly, but I still kept on getting the same deployment error DEP3321.

I solved this issue in this way -
Just go to the "Solution Explorer", on the right side of Visual Studio and do the following steps in this order -

1) Just right click on the project you are deploying

2) Press "Unload Project"

3) Right click on the project_name(unavailable) and press Edit project_name.jsproj. It will open an xml file on left hand side

4) Search for "TargetPlatformVersion" and "TargetPlatformMinVersion". Both are placed next to each other. Mine looked like this - 
    10.0.15063.0
    10.0.15063.0
since mine Error DEP3321 explicitly stated that 'you are currently running version 10.0.14393.1715, so I replaced my "TargetPlatformMinVersion" from 10.0.15063.0 to 10.0.14393.1715 -
10.0.14393.1715

5) Now save it, Ctrl+S

6) Right click on "Solution Explorer" and press Reload Project and press Yes to the popup if you get stating that project is already loaded.

You are done. Just do what you normally do, Build (ctrl+shift+B) and then Debug - F5 or Ctrl+F5.
This way the project got deployed for me.