# Visual Studio 2017 windowsmobile compilation error

Tags: uwp

My question is about compilation error stating that windowsmobile 1007134 is missing. 
I have installed, I think, everything possible of the addons to VS 2017 yet this problem arises.
I did search over google regarding this issue, found a couple of solutions, but none actually worked, or rather were way to complicated to apply.

What am I supposed to do?

Note:
My installation path of the IDE and extras is in another drive (D:).
Do I need to change or redirect a path value or something like that?

I can compile everything else except UWP programs.
Also, I'm not sure which edition of the SDK should be used in Target and minimum.
I suppose it is 1007134 which is stated in the compile error information regarding both target and minimum settings.

Please tell me to about a solution as simple as possible. Maybe an exe installation fix?

I cannot come up with anything else which I think imagine be the matter of failure right now.

I hope you maybe could give me some ideas or workarounds.

Thanks!

Comment: See the similar issue and solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424025/windows-sdk-uwp-app-error-dep3321). Hope to help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the actual error you see is something like:

> Error DEP3321: To deploy this application, your deployment target
>   should be running Windows Universal Runtime version 10.0.17134.0 or
>   higher. You currently are running version 10.0.15254.158. Please
>   update your OS, or change your deployment target to a device with the
>   appropriate version

Your current minimum target of 17134 requires the Windows 10 April Update: version 1803, OS build 17134. This version is not available for Windows 10 Mobile.

The latest build of Windows 10 Mobile available is 15245. To run on Windows 10 Mobile you will need to have a minimum target of 15245 or less (generally 15064).

You will not be able to use features newer than those in 15245 on Windows Mobile. For Windows Runtime features you can use the [Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation) class to ensure that a new API exists and is available before calling it. If the new functionality isn't available then the app will need to either not use it or revert to an available way to achieve similar effects.

ApiInformation doesn't work for the .Net Framework itself, so you won't be able to use .Net Standard 2.0 (supported for UWP starting in 16299) in an app with a lower minimum target.

To use .Net Standard 2.0 you will need to fork your app and provide different builds for current versions and for Windows 10 Mobile.

For more info see my blog entry [Why can’t I deploy my UWP app with .Net Standard 2.0 to a Mobile device or emulator?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2018/02/14/why-cant-i-deploy-my-uwp-app-with-net-standard-2-0-to-a-mobile-device-or-emulator/)